# google custom search engine execute does not show the results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

learning web application. I had usually been in firmware and desktop application software development. I have done a few web pages before, but not as intensive to say a competent front end. Back end I might have more confidence.

Anyway I followed the basic in the development like include the script:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXX';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-gname="hobbyinfo"></div>
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only" data-gname="hobbyinfo"></div>
```

then a button which onclick will call a javascript function that will execute a search.

```
function doSearch() {
    google.search.cse.element.getElement('hobbyinfo').execute('archery');
}
```

When I test the web application and just put archery on the search box and click search there is a search result showing but when I use the doSearch() nothing is showing. I am just learning google cse, facebook api, and mojolicious. But I think I am implementing the onclick correctly since I am using the simple view page where I can see the html text.

I am not sure if its correct to use "google.search.cse.element.getElement('hobbyinfo').execute('archery')" since I use HTML5 "div class="gcse-searchbox" ..." . Like I said I am not really an experienced Front End developer. Is it still correct to use google.search.cse ... if I use the 'div class="gcse-...' to create the searchbox and searchresults?

I am don't think that its because I am still just working on a virtualbox and have no real web hosting area yet, that the results are showing. Can someone tell me if this is the case?

Although when I manually do a search on the searchbox it does show the search result.

Comment: does your console display anything when you call doSearch()

Comment: No, it doesn't actually show anything. I'm not sure if it successfully found the cse. I tried the developer tools debug in the firefox browser the only error it showed me is 304 for adsync which when I looked up in the web. It should not cause any problems.

Comment: Did you check if cse actually uses that gname? `google.search.cse.element.getAllElements()` . Also put a console.log inside doSearch() to confirm it actually gets called.

Comment: Sorry I had only time to re check the code again. Yes I check doSearch it gets called. I put a console.log("Hello World"). And its showing. However your right it looks like the gname is the issue. I am getting an error message now that there is no such name as "hobbyinfo"